# Kubeflow Pipelines v2 is giving Permission Denied on OutputPath

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

In Kubeflow Pipelines v2, running on EKS with default install, I'm getting a "permission denied" error.

It ran correctly in KFP v1.

```
time="2022-04-26T21:53:30.710Z" level=info msg="capturing logs" argo=true
I0426 21:53:30.745547      18 launcher.go:144] PipelineRoot defaults to "minio://mlpipeline/v2/artifacts".
I0426 21:53:30.745908      18 cache.go:120] Connecting to cache endpoint 10.100.244.104:8887
I0426 21:53:30.854201      18 launcher.go:193] enable caching
F0426 21:53:30.979055      18 main.go:50] Failed to execute component: failed to create directory "/tmp/outputs/output_context_path" for output parameter "output_context_path": mkdir /tmp/outputs/output_context_path: permission denied
time="2022-04-26T21:53:30.980Z" level=info msg="/tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data -> /var/run/argo/outputs/artifacts/tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data.tgz" argo=true
time="2022-04-26T21:53:30.981Z" level=info msg="Taring /tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data"
Error: failed to tarball the output /tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data to /var/run/argo/outputs/artifacts/tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data.tgz: stat /tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data: permission denied
failed to tarball the output /tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data to /var/run/argo/outputs/artifacts/tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data.tgz: stat /tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data: permission denied
```

The code that produces this is here:

```
import kfp
from kfp.v2.dsl import component, Artifact, Input, InputPath, Output, OutputPath, Dataset, Model
from typing import NamedTuple

def same_step_000_afc67b36914c4108b47e8b4bb316869d_fn(
    input_context_path: InputPath(str),
    output_context_path: OutputPath(str),
    run_info: str ="gAR9lC4=",
    metadata_url: str="",
):
    from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode
    from pathlib import Path
    import datetime
    import requests
    import tempfile
    import dill
    import os

    input_context = None
    with Path(input_context_path).open("rb") as reader:
        input_context = reader.read()

    # Helper function for posting metadata to mlflow.
    def post_metadata(json):
        if metadata_url == "":
            return

        try:
            req = requests.post(metadata_url, json=json)
            req.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
            print(f"Error posting metadata: {err}")

    # Move to writable directory as user might want to do file IO.
    # TODO: won't persist across steps, might need support in SDK?
    os.chdir(tempfile.mkdtemp())

    # Load information about the current experiment run:
    run_info = dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(run_info))

    # Post session context to mlflow.
    if len(input_context) > 0:
            input_context_str = urlsafe_b64encode(input_context)
            post_metadata({
                "experiment_id": run_info["experiment_id"],
                "run_id": run_info["run_id"],
                "step_id": "same_step_000",
                "metadata_type": "input",
                "metadata_value": input_context_str,
                "metadata_time": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
            })

    # User code for step, which we run in its own execution frame.
    user_code = f"""
import dill

# Load session context into global namespace:
if { len(input_context) } > 0:
    dill.load_session("{ input_context_path }")

{dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode("gASVGAAAAAAAAACMFHByaW50KCJIZWxsbyB3b3JsZCIplC4="))}

# Remove anything from the global namespace that cannot be serialised.
# TODO: this will include things like pandas dataframes, needs sdk support?
_bad_keys = []
_all_keys = list(globals().keys())
for k in _all_keys:
    try:
        dill.dumps(globals()[k])
    except TypeError:
        _bad_keys.append(k)

for k in _bad_keys:
    del globals()[k]

# Save new session context to disk for the next component:
dill.dump_session("{output_context_path}")
"""

    # Runs the user code in a new execution frame. Context from the previous
    # component in the run is loaded into the session dynamically, and we run
    # with a single globals() namespace to simulate top-level execution.
    exec(user_code, globals(), globals())

    # Post new session context to mlflow:
    with Path(output_context_path).open("rb") as reader:
        context = urlsafe_b64encode(reader.read())
        post_metadata({
            "experiment_id": run_info["experiment_id"],
            "run_id": run_info["run_id"],
            "step_id": "same_step_000",
            "metadata_type": "output",
            "metadata_value": context,
            "metadata_time": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
        })
```

#### Environment

- How did you deploy Kubeflow Pipelines (KFP)?
  From manifests
- KFP version:
  1.8.1
- KFP SDK version:
  1.8.12

---

I *SUSPECT* this is because I'm using the native functionality in Kubeflow to write out files to a local temp directory, but I (theorize) in KFP v2 it doesn't auto-create this. Do I need to have a bucket created for this purpose on KFP v2 on AWS?

---

EDIT TWO: here's the generated yaml - line 317 is the one that worries me. It APPEARS it's putting in the string of `output_context_path` when shouldn't that be a variable? is that substituted at runtime? --

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: root-pipeline-compilation-
  annotations:
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/kfp_sdk_version: 1.8.12
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline_compilation_time: '2022-04-29T18:04:24.336927'
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline_spec: '{"inputs": [{"default": "", "name": "context",
      "optional": true, "type": "String"}, {"default": "", "name": "metadata_url",
      "optional": true, "type": "String"}, {"default": "", "name": "pipeline-root"},
      {"default": "pipeline/root_pipeline_compilation", "name": "pipeline-name"}],
      "name": "root_pipeline_compilation"}'
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_pipeline: "true"
  labels:
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_pipeline: "true"
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/kfp_sdk_version: 1.8.12
spec:
  entrypoint: root-pipeline-compilation
  templates:
  - name: root-pipeline-compilation
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - {name: metadata_url}
      - {name: pipeline-name}
      - {name: pipeline-root}
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: run-info-fn
        template: run-info-fn
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - {name: pipeline-name, value: '{{inputs.parameters.pipeline-name}}'}
          - {name: pipeline-root, value: '{{inputs.parameters.pipeline-root}}'}
      - name: same-step-000-d5554cccadc4445f91f51849eb5f2de6-fn
        template: same-step-000-d5554cccadc4445f91f51849eb5f2de6-fn
        dependencies: [run-info-fn]
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - {name: metadata_url, value: '{{inputs.parameters.metadata_url}}'}
          - {name: pipeline-name, value: '{{inputs.parameters.pipeline-name}}'}
          - {name: pipeline-root, value: '{{inputs.parameters.pipeline-root}}'}
          - {name: run-info-fn-run_info, value: '{{tasks.run-info-fn.outputs.parameters.run-info-fn-run_info}}'}
  - name: run-info-fn
    container:
      args:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |2

        if ! [ -x "$(command -v pip)" ]; then
            python3 -m ensurepip || python3 -m ensurepip --user || apt-get install python3-pip
        fi

        PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 python3 -m pip install --quiet     --no-warn-script-location 'kfp' 'dill' 'kfp==1.8.12' && "$0" "$@"
      - sh
      - -ec
      - |
        program_path=$(mktemp -d)
        printf "%s" "$0" > "$program_path/ephemeral_component.py"
        python3 -m kfp.v2.components.executor_main                         --component_module_path                         "$program_path/ephemeral_component.py"                         "$@"
      - |2+

        import kfp
        from kfp.v2 import dsl
        from kfp.v2.dsl import *
        from typing import *

        def run_info_fn(
            run_id: str,
        ) -> NamedTuple("RunInfoOutput", [("run_info", str),]):
            from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
            from collections import namedtuple
            import datetime
            import base64
            import dill
            import kfp

            client = kfp.Client(host="http://ml-pipeline:8888")
            run_info = client.get_run(run_id=run_id)

            run_info_dict = {
                "run_id": run_info.run.id,
                "name": run_info.run.name,
                "created_at": run_info.run.created_at.isoformat(),
                "pipeline_id": run_info.run.pipeline_spec.pipeline_id,
            }

            # Track kubernetes resources associated wth the run.
            for r in run_info.run.resource_references:
                run_info_dict[f"{r.key.type.lower()}_id"] = r.key.id

            # Base64-encoded as value is visible in kubeflow ui.
            output = urlsafe_b64encode(dill.dumps(run_info_dict))

            return namedtuple("RunInfoOutput", ["run_info"])(
                str(output, encoding="ascii")
            )

      - --executor_input
      - '{{$}}'
      - --function_to_execute
      - run_info_fn
      command: [/kfp-launcher/launch, --mlmd_server_address, $(METADATA_GRPC_SERVICE_HOST),
        --mlmd_server_port, $(METADATA_GRPC_SERVICE_PORT), --runtime_info_json, $(KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO),
        --container_image, $(KFP_V2_IMAGE), --task_name, run-info-fn, --pipeline_name,
        '{{inputs.parameters.pipeline-name}}', --run_id, $(KFP_RUN_ID), --run_resource,
        workflows.argoproj.io/$(WORKFLOW_ID), --namespace, $(KFP_NAMESPACE), --pod_name,
        $(KFP_POD_NAME), --pod_uid, $(KFP_POD_UID), --pipeline_root, '{{inputs.parameters.pipeline-root}}',
        --enable_caching, $(ENABLE_CACHING), --, 'run_id={{workflow.uid}}', --]
      env:
      - name: KFP_POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.name}
      - name: KFP_POD_UID
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.uid}
      - name: KFP_NAMESPACE
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.namespace}
      - name: WORKFLOW_ID
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''workflows.argoproj.io/workflow'']'}
      - name: KFP_RUN_ID
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''pipeline/runid'']'}
      - name: ENABLE_CACHING
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching'']'}
      - {name: KFP_V2_IMAGE, value: 'python:3.7'}
      - {name: KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO, value: '{"inputParameters": {"run_id": {"type":
          "STRING"}}, "inputArtifacts": {}, "outputParameters": {"run_info": {"type":
          "STRING", "path": "/tmp/outputs/run_info/data"}}, "outputArtifacts": {}}'}
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef: {name: metadata-grpc-configmap, optional: true}
      image: python:3.7
      volumeMounts:
      - {mountPath: /kfp-launcher, name: kfp-launcher}
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - {name: pipeline-name}
      - {name: pipeline-root}
    outputs:
      parameters:
      - name: run-info-fn-run_info
        valueFrom: {path: /tmp/outputs/run_info/data}
      artifacts:
      - {name: run-info-fn-run_info, path: /tmp/outputs/run_info/data}
    metadata:
      annotations:
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component: "true"
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/component_ref: '{}'
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/arguments.parameters: '{"run_id": "{{workflow.uid}}"}'
      labels:
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/kfp_sdk_version: 1.8.12
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline-sdk-type: kfp
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component: "true"
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching: "true"
    initContainers:
    - command: [launcher, --copy, /kfp-launcher/launch]
      image: gcr.io/ml-pipeline/kfp-launcher:1.8.7
      name: kfp-launcher
      mirrorVolumeMounts: true
    volumes:
    - {name: kfp-launcher}
  - name: same-step-000-d5554cccadc4445f91f51849eb5f2de6-fn
    container:
      args:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |2

        if ! [ -x "$(command -v pip)" ]; then
            python3 -m ensurepip || python3 -m ensurepip --user || apt-get install python3-pip
        fi

        PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 python3 -m pip install --quiet     --no-warn-script-location 'dill' 'requests' 'kfp==1.8.12' && "$0" "$@"
      - sh
      - -ec
      - |
        program_path=$(mktemp -d)
        printf "%s" "$0" > "$program_path/ephemeral_component.py"
        python3 -m kfp.v2.components.executor_main                         --component_module_path                         "$program_path/ephemeral_component.py"                         "$@"
      - |2+

        import kfp
        from kfp.v2 import dsl
        from kfp.v2.dsl import *
        from typing import *

        def same_step_000_d5554cccadc4445f91f51849eb5f2de6_fn(
            input_context_path: InputPath(str),
            output_context_path: OutputPath(str),
            run_info: str = "gAR9lC4=",
            metadata_url: str = "",
        ):
            from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode
            from pathlib import Path
            import datetime
            import requests
            import tempfile
            import dill
            import os

            input_context = None
            with Path(input_context_path).open("rb") as reader:
                input_context = reader.read()

            # Helper function for posting metadata to mlflow.
            def post_metadata(json):
                if metadata_url == "":
                    return

                try:
                    req = requests.post(metadata_url, json=json)
                    req.raise_for_status()
                except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
                    print(f"Error posting metadata: {err}")

            # Move to writable directory as user might want to do file IO.
            # TODO: won't persist across steps, might need support in SDK?
            os.chdir(tempfile.mkdtemp())

            # Load information about the current experiment run:
            run_info = dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(run_info))

            # Post session context to mlflow.
            if len(input_context) > 0:
                    input_context_str = urlsafe_b64encode(input_context)
                    post_metadata({
                        "experiment_id": run_info["experiment_id"],
                        "run_id": run_info["run_id"],
                        "step_id": "same_step_000",
                        "metadata_type": "input",
                        "metadata_value": input_context_str,
                        "metadata_time": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
                    })

            # User code for step, which we run in its own execution frame.
            user_code = f"""
        import dill

        # Load session context into global namespace:
        if { len(input_context) } > 0:
            dill.load_session("{ input_context_path }")

        {dill.loads(urlsafe_b64decode("gASVGAAAAAAAAACMFHByaW50KCJIZWxsbyB3b3JsZCIplC4="))}

        # Remove anything from the global namespace that cannot be serialised.
        # TODO: this will include things like pandas dataframes, needs sdk support?
        _bad_keys = []
        _all_keys = list(globals().keys())
        for k in _all_keys:
            try:
                dill.dumps(globals()[k])
            except TypeError:
                _bad_keys.append(k)

        for k in _bad_keys:
            del globals()[k]

        # Save new session context to disk for the next component:
        dill.dump_session("{output_context_path}")
        """

            # Runs the user code in a new execution frame. Context from the previous
            # component in the run is loaded into the session dynamically, and we run
            # with a single globals() namespace to simulate top-level execution.
            exec(user_code, globals(), globals())

            # Post new session context to mlflow:
            with Path(output_context_path).open("rb") as reader:
                context = urlsafe_b64encode(reader.read())
                post_metadata({
                    "experiment_id": run_info["experiment_id"],
                    "run_id": run_info["run_id"],
                    "step_id": "same_step_000",
                    "metadata_type": "output",
                    "metadata_value": context,
                    "metadata_time": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
                })

      - --executor_input
      - '{{$}}'
      - --function_to_execute
      - same_step_000_d5554cccadc4445f91f51849eb5f2de6_fn
      command: [/kfp-launcher/launch, --mlmd_server_address, $(METADATA_GRPC_SERVICE_HOST),
        --mlmd_server_port, $(METADATA_GRPC_SERVICE_PORT), --runtime_info_json, $(KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO),
        --container_image, $(KFP_V2_IMAGE), --task_name, same-step-000-d5554cccadc4445f91f51849eb5f2de6-fn,
        --pipeline_name, '{{inputs.parameters.pipeline-name}}', --run_id, $(KFP_RUN_ID),
        --run_resource, workflows.argoproj.io/$(WORKFLOW_ID), --namespace, $(KFP_NAMESPACE),
        --pod_name, $(KFP_POD_NAME), --pod_uid, $(KFP_POD_UID), --pipeline_root, '{{inputs.parameters.pipeline-root}}',
        --enable_caching, $(ENABLE_CACHING), --, input_context_path=, 'metadata_url={{inputs.parameters.metadata_url}}',
        'run_info={{inputs.parameters.run-info-fn-run_info}}', --]
      env:
      - name: KFP_POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.name}
      - name: KFP_POD_UID
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.uid}
      - name: KFP_NAMESPACE
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.namespace}
      - name: WORKFLOW_ID
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''workflows.argoproj.io/workflow'']'}
      - name: KFP_RUN_ID
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''pipeline/runid'']'}
      - name: ENABLE_CACHING
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching'']'}
      - {name: KFP_V2_IMAGE, value: 'public.ecr.aws/j1r0q0g6/notebooks/notebook-servers/codeserver-python:v1.5.0'}
      - {name: KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO, value: '{"inputParameters": {"input_context_path":
          {"type": "STRING"}, "metadata_url": {"type": "STRING"}, "run_info": {"type":
          "STRING"}}, "inputArtifacts": {}, "outputParameters": {"output_context_path":
          {"type": "STRING", "path": "/tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data"}}, "outputArtifacts":
          {}}'}
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef: {name: metadata-grpc-configmap, optional: true}
      image: public.ecr.aws/j1r0q0g6/notebooks/notebook-servers/codeserver-python:v1.5.0
      volumeMounts:
      - {mountPath: /kfp-launcher, name: kfp-launcher}
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - {name: metadata_url}
      - {name: pipeline-name}
      - {name: pipeline-root}
      - {name: run-info-fn-run_info}
    outputs:
      artifacts:
      - {name: same-step-000-d5554cccadc4445f91f51849eb5f2de6-fn-output_context_path,
        path: /tmp/outputs/output_context_path/data}
    metadata:
      annotations:
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component: "true"
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/component_ref: '{}'
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/arguments.parameters: '{"input_context_path": "", "metadata_url":
          "{{inputs.parameters.metadata_url}}", "run_info": "{{inputs.parameters.run-info-fn-run_info}}"}'
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/max_cache_staleness: P0D
      labels:
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/kfp_sdk_version: 1.8.12
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline-sdk-type: kfp
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component: "true"
        pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching: "true"
    initContainers:
    - command: [launcher, --copy, /kfp-launcher/launch]
      image: gcr.io/ml-pipeline/kfp-launcher:1.8.7
      name: kfp-launcher
      mirrorVolumeMounts: true
    volumes:
    - {name: kfp-launcher}
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - {name: context, value: ''}
    - {name: metadata_url, value: ''}
    - {name: pipeline-root, value: ''}
    - {name: pipeline-name, value: pipeline/root_pipeline_compilation}
  serviceAccountName: pipeline-runner
```

It's DEFINITELY a regression - here's the same YAML generated with the two compiler flags on. The first works, the second doesn't.

- using the compiler in v1 mode - https://gist.github.com/aronchick/0dfc57d2a794c1bd4fb9bff9962cfbd6
- using the compiler in v2 mode - https://gist.github.com/aronchick/473060503ae189b360fbded04d802c80

Comment: I'm running into the same issue as you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319175/boto3-cannot-save-artifact-to-outputpath-in-kubeflow-pipeline ... Your theory make sense but I don't know how to force creation of a local tmp folder